# Using wc_update_order_item_meta to update product variation price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Im trying to update woocommerce order item price if its a variable product.

The issue im having is it only seems to be getting the first price of the woocommerce product variation and uses that for each item variation in the order even if its a different variation, it should get the price from the correct variation id but im not to sure what ive missed out?.

Code below:

```
    function update_variable_product_price( ){

        $query = new WC_Order_Query( array(
            'status' => 'on-hold',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'return' => 'ids',
        ) );
        $order_ids = $query->get_orders();

        foreach( $order_ids as $order_id ) {


            $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
            $items = $order->get_items();


            echo "Order Number: ". $order_id;
            echo "</br>";
            echo "Product Name: ". $order_id["name"];
            echo "</br>";


            foreach ($items as $item) {

                $product_name = $item->get_name();
                $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
                $product_variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
                $product_variation_price = $item->get_total();
                $product = new WC_Product_Variable($product_id);#1 Get product variations
                $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
                $product_qty = $item['qty'];

                echo "</br>-----------------";
                echo "Product Name: " . $product_name;
                echo "</br>";
                echo  "Qty".$product_qty;
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Product Price: " . $product_variation_price;
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Product ID: " . $product_id;
                echo "</br>";
                echo "Variation ID: " . $product_variation_id;
                echo "</br>";
                var_dump($product_variations)  ;
                echo "</br>";


                foreach ($product_variations as $product_variation) {
                    $variation_product_id = $product_variation ['variation_id'];

                    $variation_product = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_product_id);


                    echo "</br>";
                    echo $variation_product->get_price();
                    echo "</br>";
                    echo $variation_product->get_id();
                    echo "</br>";
                    if (isset($product_variation_id)){

                        if($product_id == $product_variation_id) {
                            return wc_update_order_item_meta($item->$product_id, $product_variation_id, $variation_product->get_price());
                        }


                    }
                }
            }  
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry im trying to update the item total price for each order with a product variation.  For example a order has: Product 1 - Red is £55.25 & Product 2 - Blue £45.99. I want it to update price from the current product page sale price for: Product 1 - Red & Product 2 - Blue. As the price may get lowered so if Product 1 - Red is now 35.99 then it should update that on the orders from £55.25 to 35.99. This doesn't account for taxes

Comment: See my answer to your last question… You are complicating things for nothing and there is quiet a lot of mistakes and errors in your actual code… You should better use only CRUD methods introduced with Woocommerce 3.